# Which are some good algorithms and heuristics to calculate the similarity between two matrices?

Tags: algorithms, matrix, approximation

Say I have a matrix like this:

\begin{bmatrix}
    0  & 0 & 0 &  1 \\
    0  & 0 & 1 &  1 \\
    0 & 1 & 1 &  1 \\
\end{bmatrix}

And this one:

\begin{bmatrix}
    0  & 0 & 0 &  1 \\
    0  & 0 & 1 &  1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 &  1 \\
\end{bmatrix}

The difference between this two matrices is 2 elements in 12, or 16,67%.
So, I can say that they have 83,33% similarity.Which are some good algorithms or heuristics(I don't need more precision than +- 5%) to get this number(the 83,33% on this case) other than the naive algorithm that walk both matrices and compare each element using a nested loop structure?

Comment: Are your matrices binary matrices?

Comment: @nicoguaro not necessarily

Comment: I would use a norm of the difference of the two matrices, then.

Comment: @nicoguaro can you elaborate that on an answer?

Comment: How is similarity defined for non-binary matrices? Do you just check if the elements are equal or not? Or do you take into account somehow the magnitude of their difference?

Comment: How can you access the matrices? If all you can do is querying $A(i,j)$ for given $i,j$, then I don't see how you can expect to get anything better than the naive algorithm. You don't know what is in a location until you access it, so you have to make at least $O(n^2)$ reads.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: "it depends".

But the first question that is not entirely clear from the question is a *definition of similarity* between two matrices. Technically there is a term [Matrix similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity), but there is certainly nothing common between it and what you are asking.

To justify the inquiry about the *similarity definition*, consider three matrices:

$$
A_1=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 &0 &0 \\
1 &1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right], \quad
A_2=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 &1 &1 \\
0 &1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right],\quad
A_3=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 &0 &0 \\
0 &1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]
$$
Here, $A_1 = A_2^T$. However, according to element-wise similarity definition you proposed, the difference between them will be huge: 2/3. Moreover, the identity matrix $A_3=I_3$ has a smaller difference of just 1/3.

Other examples demonstrating more complicated similarities/differences between two matrices can be shown.

Nevertheless, let's assume that we are just interested performing strict element-to-element in two matrices. A natural metric would be the one that *nicoguaro* suggested:
$
\left|\left| A_1-A_2 \right|\right|_{1,2,F,\ldots}
$
Here, $1,2,F,\ldots$ in the subscript correspond to different matrix norms (1-norm, 2-norm, Frobenius norm, etc.) Unfortunately, the calculation of the norm requires at least browsing through all the elements of the matrix $A_1-A_2$. And it will be not easy to come up with the speed-up of that calculation without knowing where your matrix comes from.

There are various algorithms that will be able to estimate your norm, provided some information:

- [A Matrix-Free, Transpose-Free Norm Estimator, First IMA International Conference on Numerical Linear Algebra and Optimisation, Birmingham, UK, 13-15 September 2007](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~ipsen/ps/slides_ima.pdf) - requires a matrix-vector product.
- [A. Heldring, E. Ubeda, J. M. Rius, "Stochastic Estimation of the Frobenius Norm in the ACA Convergence Criterion," *IEEE Antennas Propagat.*, vol. 63, no. 3, pp. 1155-1158, Mar. 2015.](https://doi.org/10.1109/TAP.2014.2386306) - using adaptive cross approximation, which is efficient if your matrix is low-rank to begin with.

But I think all that is an overkill. At this moment, there is no justification why a naïve algorithm for calculating a norm of a matrix $A_1-A_2$ is not sufficient. Since, even if the size of the matrix is large, you are storing them in the memory anyway; thus, you certainly can afford to compute at least the Frobenius norm.